# How to Validate This Statistical Framework?

Tags: statistics, mathematical-modeling

I have a framework to assess trust score of data based on similarity measure. Data with higher similarity among all other data will have higher trust score.

Is there any way to validate this framework? Maybe something like precision and recall to validate prediction model.

Thanks in advance.